# Request to acquire token failed (org.xml.sax.SAXParseException)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I am using this code to get token using username and password and it fails with SAXParseException - Can anyone help?

Code

```
    AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/",false, service);
    Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken("&ltresource&gt", "clientId","userLogin","password",null);
    AuthenticationResult result = future.get();
    System.out.println("Access Token - " + result.getAccessToken());
    System.out.println("Refresh Token - " + result.getRefreshToken());
    System.out.println("ID Token - " + result.getIdToken());
```

Exception in logs:

```
 
    [Correlation ID: null] Sent (null) Correlation Id is not same as received (null).
    [Correlation ID: null] Sent (null) Correlation Id is not same as received (null).
    [Correlation ID: 94f119e8-04bd-431e-9101-dbfb7d9c5a42] Request to acquire token failed.
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.MexParser.getPolicy(MexParser.java:101)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.MexParser.getWsTrustEndpointFromMexResponse(MexParser.java:141)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.WSTrustRequest.execute(WSTrustRequest.java:84)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.processPasswordGrant(AuthenticationContext.java:990)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$000(AuthenticationContext.java:69)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:178)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:168)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    [Fatal Error] :12:10: DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 10; DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
        at O365RestClient.main(O365RestClient.java:32)
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 10; DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.MexParser.getPolicy(MexParser.java:101)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.MexParser.getWsTrustEndpointFromMexResponse(MexParser.java:141)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.WSTrustRequest.execute(WSTrustRequest.java:84)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.processPasswordGrant(AuthenticationContext.java:990)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$000(AuthenticationContext.java:69)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:178)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:168)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    [Correlation ID: 94f119e8-04bd-431e-9101-dbfb7d9c5a42] Request to acquire token failed.
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 10; DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.MexParser.getPolicy(MexParser.java:101)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.MexParser.getWsTrustEndpointFromMexResponse(MexParser.java:141)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.WSTrustRequest.execute(WSTrustRequest.java:84)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.processPasswordGrant(AuthenticationContext.java:990)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$000(AuthenticationContext.java:69)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:178)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:168)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```